# Weird problem: collection object displaying in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I run the following code in the view:

```
- if @object.winner.present? && @object.winner.prizes.any?
  %ul
    = @object.winner.prizes.each do |p|
      %li= p.description.html_safe
```

It's returning this:

```
li prize1
li prize2
li prize3
...
[#<Prize object...> ... ]
```

Does anyone know why it is listing the @object.winner.prizes collection in the view directly after the last @object.winner.prizes object is displayed?

Extremely baffled! I'm using Rails v3.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `=` when you should be using `-` to iterate over the objects:

```
- @object.winner.prizes.each do |p|
```

Comment: OMG, I am such a dumb @$$! Bedtime for me I guess!